# Class has no field named 'p'

Tags: wagtail

I have following model class and and list_filter inside wagtail_hooks.py and when I will create "Spieler" i get this error

[image]

and here is my traceback
http://dpaste.com/3A5QAH0

```
#models.py
POSITIONS_SP = (
    ('th', 'TH'),
    ('st', 'ST'),
    ('vt', 'VT'))
POSITIONS_SP_LOOKUP = dict(POSITIONS_SP)

class Spieler(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    vorname = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=POSITIONS_SP)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name', classname="col6"),
        FieldPanel('vorname', classname="col6"),
        FieldPanel('position', classname="col4"),
    ]

#wagtail_hooks.py
class SpielerModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Spieler
    menu_label = 'Spieler'
    menu_icon = 'group'
    list_display = ('name', 'vorname', 'position')
    search_fields = ('name', 'vorname')
    list_filter = ('position')
```

When I remove list_filter all works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a tuple with only one item in it, you need to add a trailing comma:

```
list_filter = ('position',)
```

Otherwise, Python will interpret the parentheses as meaning "evaluate this first" (as you'd use when calculating something like `(2 + 2) * 3`), giving the result `'position'`, and will try to interpret that string as a list - and so it ends up looping over every character in `'position'`.

Alternatively, you can use list notation to make it unambiguous:

```
list_filter = ['position']
```